# What is the Literal "Up" Key Escape Sequence in Golang

Tags: go, telnet

I'm writing a Go program to communicate with a server over Telnet.  It has an interactive little program (which I have heard can be made with something called "curses"--no familiarity there).

While I can send "enter" with the likes of `"\r\n"` I find myself needing to send an "up" key.  How do I write a literal "up" key in my Go code, with any and all appropriate escape sequences, in a way that will send properly to the server?

Comment: According to [curses.h](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libcurses/curses.h?rev=1.86&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup), try `0x103` for `KEY_UP`, e.g. try both `[]byte{0x01, 0x03}` for big-endian or `[]byte{0x03, 0x01}` for little-endian.

Comment: You need to make yourself familiar with curses.

Comment: The answer depends solely on the terminal (emulator) used and is totally unrelated to Go.

Answer (score 0):

`\x1b` is the escape sequence.  CSI codes per [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) worked, so it was `\x1ba` to move the cursor up one row.